# Matlab: reading images from folder does not return filenames in order

Tags: image, matlab, io, readfile

I am reading `jpg` files from a folder. My code is as follows:

```
inputImg= dir('C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\TestImages\*.jpg');
inputDir = 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\TestImages\';
inputN = {inputImg.name};

for i = 1:numel(dstNFiles)

    dstFileName = dstImageFiles(i).name;
    dstName = strcat(dstDir,dstFileName);
    image = imread(dstName);
    %% do some work here
end
```

All those `jpg` images in my forlder are orderly named in the manner `"01.jpg, 02.jpg,...200.jpg"`. But I found that it is not reading these files in order. I tried to print the `dstFileName`, and it gives totally random ordered filenames, like:

```
01.jpg, 02.jpg, 03.jpg, 04.jpg,05.jpg,06.jpg,07.jpg,08.jpg,09.jpg,10.jpg,100.jpg,101.jpg,11.jpg, ... 199.jpg,200.jpg, 24.jpg,25.jpg,...
```

How could I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file list is in the correct alphabetic order!

Consider using padding when saving.

Ie. save 10.jpg as 0010.jpg

If you can't change the file name you have to write your own ordering function.